# Kinetic energy transfer in matter annihilation?

Tags: particle-physics, special-relativity, energy-conservation

What happens to the kinetic energy of matter when it is annihilated? Is it released in the resultant explosion? In that case shouldn't it be $E=(mc^2 + \frac{1}{2} mv^2)$ ?

Answer (score 3):

It is. At low speeds, the energy of a particle can be suitably approximated as $E = mc^2 + \frac{1}{2}mv^2$.

The true formula, which is valid at any speed, is

$$E = \frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$

Note that both of these answers are the same: the first is the first two terms in a Taylor approximation of the second.  The case in which $E = mc^2 + \frac{1}{2}mv^2$ is not appropriate is the case when the third term in the series, $\frac{3mv^4}{8c^2}$ is large enough to be important.